# Odd behavior of os

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a Python script that will take any playlist and recreate it on another file structure. I have it written now so that all the filenames are stripped off the original playlist and put into a file.  That works.  Then the function findsong() is supposed to walk thru the new directory and find the same songs and make a new playlist based on the new directory structure.

Here's where it gets weird.  If I use 'line' as my argument in the line 'If line in files' I get an empty new playlist.  If I use ANY file that I know is there as the argument the entire playlist is recreated, not just the file I used as the argument. That's how I have it set up in this code. I cannot figure out this weird behavior.  As long as the file exists, the whole playlist is recreated with the new paths.  Wut??

Here is the code:

```
import os

def check():

    datafile = open('testlist.m3u')
    nopath = open('nopath.txt', 'w')
    nopath.truncate()

    for line in datafile:
        if 'mp3' in line:
            nopath.write(os.path.basename(line))

        if 'wma' in line:
            nopath.write(os.path.basename(line))
    nopath.close()

def findsong():

    nopath = open('nopath.txt')
    squeezelist = open('squeezelist.m3u' ,'w')
    squeezelist.truncate()
    for line in nopath:
        print line

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:\\Documents and Settings\\"):
            print files

            if ' Tuesday\'s Gone.mp3' in files:
                squeezelist.write(os.path.join(root, line))

    squeezelist.close()


check()

findsong()
```

Comment: You definitely don't want to iterate the list of all files _again and again_ for each of the lines in `nopath`. Rather create a set from one of them (the lines or the files) and use set lookup to see if songs match.

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over the lines in a file Python retains the trailing newlines `\n`. You'll want to strip those off:

```
for line in nopath:
    line = line.rstrip()
```